# Conditional Formatting w/multiple conditions and partial text match

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am working in google sheets and  have a manual input quantity in column E. I am trying to write a conditional format that will highlight each cell in column E (or the whole row) that is greater than 1 only if column C's matching row begins with "EM". I have a few variations but this is closest that could seem to work but cells that do not match the conditions are getting highlighted and cells with the conditions are being omitted...

=and(regexmatch(C2,"EM"),E2>1)

I know I will need some wildcards in there but I tried a few different combo's already with no luck. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cells that do not match the conditions are getting highlighted and cells with the conditions are being omitted

That sound like you need a [`NOT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305?hl=en) to negate the result.

> column C's matching row begins with "EM"

The regular expression now matches all content which *contains* EM, so you probably need to replace the argument with `"^EM"`; the caret indicates the beginning of the content. (That's a standard regex operator; as indicated [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en), Google Sheets uses the RE2 version.)

You could try this:

```
=not(and(regexmatch(C2,"^EM"),E2>1))
```

and see whether it works for you.

Comment: I attempted the adding of the "not" for the scenario with and without the caret. I attempted using the caret notation earlier. And this confirms there is something that sheets does not like about it. All I was thinking I could do was to add wild cards to count the reaming characters, ^EM*****? but this is new for me. Here is a copy of what Im working on. The cells referenced are in the Check-out tabhttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1prFAAy_NF_uigqZo7q3kuYq1JapDAC1xzpr6fHCahuY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Never mind. This seemed to work on the copied version of the doc. I will have to look into further to why its not working on my master. Thanks for the help!